# Typing a objects field value with the value of its sibling in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

does anyone knows how to type an object field depending on the sibling value?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUwE8IBXGAHgBUA+OAbwCg45cAbNgZwC44AKQiXLU6AHzgBBchADCwDgAUoEMJxEBKANoBdANyMAvo0ahIsODCJg8UmLPlslKtVQA0cAGJxQqJABNOOABrYBJ0OCo4AF5g0Ihw2mjJaQkoKGInVWp3Dxp9E3BoeGRUDBwbFLSM5Sy3TwR5P28QXwDYsIi6JhY-TBhMKitgXgByVPSiEf0WJEwAW2H6xum4NmIyGF5BDepNDwa2P208w2NLazh0aDmAET7MJO64TmBsGAQIJABGXnp0A78P2eMCgyAA5gZXMxnq93p8AEy-f6NRHA0FICFQozYT6ceBrISbAjrYRXKC3e50GJPdhcXiaaFPHr3QbWUbjYgjKEsGbzRYjF5vD7fLnQlgEja8CgAWllcAA7pgUBYABYIQJ2OAAIzwjAA9HqeUbtsImAajRaWMjDkC8eiwfpzQZLXAaNDIYyxXBev1WfyOZNuTzZgtRoK4Uh4aKjRLyFLZdKFUr4DA1RqINrdebLSbKGbDS6eda-Ki7eDHYbnZa3SxndDtIYgA)

here i have a layout type which ultimatly resolves into a cell type but a cells can have a layout which should take the type of the field.

```
export interface Layout<T> {
  cells: (Layout<T> | AutoCellProps<T>)[];
}

export type AutoCellProps<T, F extends keyof T = keyof T> = AutoArrayProps<T, F>;

export interface AutoArrayProps<T, Field extends keyof T> {
  dataType: 'Array';
  name: Field;
  layout: Layout<T[Field]>;
}

type formData = {
  section1: {field1: string},
  section2: {field2: string},
}
const layout: Layout<formData> = {
  cells: [
  {
    dataType: 'Array',
    name: 'section1',
    layout: <--- want this to be 
//       Layout<{
//           field1: string;
// }       >
  },
  {
    dataType: 'Array',
    name: 'section2',
    layout: <--- want this to be 
//       Layout<{
//           field2: string;
// }       >
  } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your linked playground has a bunch of errors seemingly unrelated to the question. It'd be helpful if you could fix it to show your problem only.

Comment: @MikeS. found the answer i have commented it here, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to use conditional operator to check if the field exists, still not sure how it work but posting the answer here and also the link where I found the answer

instead of

```
export type AutoCellProps<T, F extends keyof T = keyof T> = AutoArrayProps<T, F>
```

using the following did the trick

```
export type AutoCellProps<T, F extends keyof T = keyof T> = F extends keyof T ? AutoArrayProps<T, F> : never;
```

found the answer here -> https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32673#issuecomment-517655996

if anyone understood why the type resolves to a union without the operator please comment